# http://blog.elementary.io/ direct to https://www.datenschutz.de/?

Tags: networking, elementary-website

why http://blog.elementary.io/ direct to https://www.datenschutz.de/ ? is it normal ? date 2016 10 24

Comment: Doesn't for me.  I assume you're in Germany - perhaps your ISP has a redirect in place, or perhaps the computer you're visiting from is infected by malware, and gets redirected by your ISP for all pages?

Comment: Please can you post the output of `dig blog.elementary.io` and `dig @8.8.8.8 blog.elementary.io`?

Comment: You might need to install `dnsutils` to get the `dig` utility.

Answer (score 1):

Looks ok for me, may it is a problem with your ISP. [image]